# Is there a way to write protractor tests to test on devices plugged into my pc not via browserstack

Tags: protractor, quality-assurance, typescript

we are trying to save some money and  have devices here already to test on, is there a way i can setup my tests to run on them ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should try using Appium.  Java + Appium definitely works.  Plug in your mobile device, start the Appium server, and run your tests.

I am not sure if Protractor supports running native apps on physical devices.

Here is a good place to start.  Then search online to see where others have had success.

http://www.protractortest.org/#/mobile-setup